# How to tabindex on element with opacity set to 0

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I have a drag and drop image upload field, where I have set the input field to opacity 0 so the upload button doesn't show up so I can style it to fit the mock-up. However, I am trying to address accessibility concerns by making the upload functionality trigger when the user presses enter.

The problem I am having is, since the opacity is set to 0 when I tab to it, it doesn't focus the element. I can still press enter to upload the file and that works fine, but there is no indicator for the user to know the option is there for them.

Is there a good way to remedy that?

Here is a small example of what I am doing:

HTML:

```
<div class="imageUploader">
    <input class="upload" type="file" accept="image/*">
    <p class="text"> Drop your photo here or upload a file</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imageUploader {
    width: 120px;
    height: 122px;
    background-color: #F4F6FC;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.image {
    opacity:0;
    width: 100%
    height: 120px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
} 

.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of what you have done to your question.

Comment: You can place a label next to your invisible field and target it in CSS with the adjacent sibling combinator: `input[type="file"]:focus + label.upload-indicator`, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should allow you to click on the custom circle with text to open the file input.  It also allows you to tab to it and a visual cue is displayed to indicate the element is focused.

```css
.imageUploader {
    width: 120px;
    height: 122px;
    background-color: #F4F6FC;
    border-radius: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.upload {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 122px;
  height: 122px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.upload:focus + .imageUploader {
     border:1px solid #4D90FE;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="inputID" class="upload" type="file" accept="image/*">
    <label for="inputID" class="imageUploader">Drop your photo here or upload a file</label>
</div>
```